# Populate a ComboBox in a DataGrid in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, combobox

How can I show the items of the `List<string> Sections` as a `Combobox` under the Sections field in a DataGrid myDataGrid.

```
List<string> Sections = new List<string> {"C50", "C40", "C30"};
```

[image]

Currently I'm using the below code to populate the rest of the fields in myDataGrid.

```
var data = from row in Building.Columns
            select new
            {
                row.Id,
                row.X,
                row.Y,
                row.StartElevation,
                row.EndElevation,
                row.FoundationHeight,
                Sections = ""
            };
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
```

Comment: Show your xaml please

Comment: `<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            </DataGrid>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` you should using `AutoGeneratingColumn` event ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="myDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void myDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Sections")
    {
        var cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
        cb.Header = "Sections";
        cb.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "C50", "C40", "C30" };
        cb.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Sections");
        e.Column = cb;
    }        
}
```

Solution with `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` :

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="StartElevation" Binding="{Binding StartElevation}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="EndElevation" Binding="{Binding EndElevation}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FoundationHeight" Binding="{Binding FoundationHeight}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cbSections" Header="Sections" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Sections}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
...
{
...
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = data;

cbSections.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "C50", "C40", "C30" }; 
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please kindly check the code for Solution with `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Vahid did you get any error messages? I made example solution for you: http://1drv.ms/1mqX8Ga.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort you put into this, I was really stuck and I truly appreciate it. Just one thing, the combobox appears when I doubleclick the cell, it is not visible before that. Is this the normal behavior?

Comment: @Vahid yes, it's the normal behavior. When it's not in the edit state it just display selected value.